# What's the exact complexity of a DFS if we revisit nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, directed-acyclic-graph, complexity

By "revisit nodes," I mean if we didn't maintain a set of nodes we have visited. So the sum I'm examining is just the number of paths from a root to a node, across all roots and nodes. We'll also only consider DAGs for obvious reasons.

Imaginably, this is a hard query to google for. I'm looking for a complexity that is more precise than just "exponential" - is there some nice property of a graph that expresses this? For example, it would be convenient if the complexity would be linear if we the graph is just a tree. Maybe treewidth is helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the graph has an adjacency matrix $M$. It's well known that the number of paths of length $k$ from $i$ to $j$ is $(M^k)_{ij}$. Since we care about paths of any length, we are interested in $M^0 + M^1 + M^2 + \dots = (I - M)^{-1}$. In particular, the vector $(I - M)^{-1} \bf{1}$ has in its $i$th position the number of paths starting from $i$.

Comment: That's neat but unfortunately not really useful . This seems even harder to put a bound on, and I'm guessing that trees don't obviously satisfy the property I want through this lens.